# suscpicion of package overshadowing \def command

Tags: macros

In the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\def\tag{hello}
\newcommand{\createfig}{%                                                                                                                  
  \def\tag{hey}%                                                                                                                              
  \begin{figure}
    \subfloat[caption]{%                                                                                                                      
      \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}%                                                                            
    }%                                                                                                                                        
    \caption{some caption}
    \label{fig:\tag}
  \end{figure}
}%                                                                                                                                            
\begin{document}
\tag
\createfig
\end{document}
```

I receive an error:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.20 \createfig
```

The problem can be resolved by

- renaming `\tag` to `\tagl`
- or removing `\usepackage{amsmath}`

I suspect the `\tag{label}` command from the `amsmath` package is interfering with the workings of the `\tag` defined in `\createfig`.

However, this is not at all visible in the error message. How might it be possible and how to resolve such cases?

The case is even more curious as the other `\tag` defined outside the `\createfig` environment functions normally.

Comment: @TorbjornT, yes changing `\def` into `\newcomand` shows an error, `! LaTeX Error: Command \tag already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you modify your example to

```
\show\tag
\label{fig:\tag}
```

You will see that the definition of `\tag` at that point is:

```
> \tag=macro:
->\invalid@tag {\string \tag \space not allowed here}.
l.17 \show\tag
```

Which is not safe in a `\label`.

`amsmath` installs that definition so that the equation numbering command is not used out of math mode. In particlular it adds `\default@tag` (which resets the meaning of `\tag`) to `\@parboxrestore` so it is reset every float or parbox, minipage etc.

Comment: How can what I do inside a `\label` affect the `\caption` above?

Comment: @Viesturs I clarified it a bit more.